# How to do multiple if, else statements in this case in bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, sh

Right now I am running a few programs with bash scripts (with Cygwin).

Basically what I am doing is after the program is starting, a loop is ran that checks that the program is still running.

I was doing:

```
while true
do
    if [ "$(ps -W | grep -w name | gawk '{print $8,$9}' | gawk -F \\ '{print $4}')" == 'program' ];then 
        sleep 1
    else
        "start program" (whatever is needed here)
    fi
done
```

But I started to realize having such a script multiple times is just causing unnecessary system resources to be used.

I tried doing an if then, elif, but it never goes past the first if.

I need it to go "alright the first if is negative, try the next, go to the end, start over".

Here is the copy of my script and I forgot to say I was using Cygwin but that really doesn't change anything cause it seems to still use normal bash scripting just maybe different paths to start files. http://pastebin.com/s8ZdPQMn and yes the h. is not there I just can't seem to edit the pastebin.

My overall plan is check that first SRPro is running, check the next, etc, only triggering if it's detected one is not running.

EDIT: I solved it. Not exactly sure why but in my original single file per program, gawk printing $4 at the end gave me what I wanted, but for some reason when doing it this way, it turned to $5. So changing $4 to $5 made the script work.

EDIT: One really strange issue though is, it will work minutes on end, then all the sudden get confused at times, and start 7 copies of one program or something. Also it can be random on which it starts.

Comment: You must be starting the program in background, i.e. `name &`? Can you instead run it in foreground, `name`, so that the control continues in script only after it finishes?

Comment: Show use the code for your if-elif-else block?

Comment: You might want to clarify what your eventual goal is. It's good that you have showed one of the things that you tried; but it's hard to tell from your question what you are trying to do. Are you trying to run multiple processes, monitor them, and if they exit restart them?

Comment: Instead of using `ps`/`gawk` magic, you should use [`pgrep`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pgrep)

Answer (score 1):

You might find the `wait` command (try `help wait` from a bash prompt) useful. It's unclear exactly what you want, but as an example, here's a basic respawn function:

```
$ respawn () {
>   while true
>   do
>     "${@}" &
>     wait ${!}
>     echo "respawning ..."
>   done
> }
$ respawn some_program arg1 arg2 etc
```

Comment: I've seen this before here on S.O., and my experience (or more likely lack of) makes me wonder: what is the value of running something in the background, but then waiting, and only to restart it? Why not just `while true "${@}" ; echo "restarting"; done` ?  Does running in the background give some opportunity for control that I don't see? Good luck to all.

Comment: You're right that the example I've given is pointless - it's intended merely as an example of how to use `wait`.

Comment: ok, np. I can see that this might provide a base for solution for O.P. Just wanted to be sure that I wasn't missing some great feature. Good luck to all.